# Can't find Delayed Job record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I'm new to [Delayed Jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and am not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

**Worker**

```
class BillingFailedEmailWorker < BaseWorker

  attr_accessor :car

  def initialize(car)
     @car = car 
  end

  def billing_failed_for_subscriptions
    StripeMailer::billing_failed_for_subscriptions(car.owner.email).deliver
  end

  def perform
    self.class.new(car).delay(
      run_at: DateTime.now + 1.week,
      queue: "Failed Subscription"
    ).billing_failed_for_subscriptions
  end  
end
```

**Mailer**

```
class StripeMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: Settings.default_from_email

  def billing_failed_for_subscriptions(email)
    mail to: email, subject: 'Autobrain Subscription Renewal Failed'
  end
end
```

`billing_failed_for_subscriptions` also obviously corresponds to the correct mailer view.

My question is when I run `BillingFailedEmailWorker.new(Car.last).perform` I see the command execute correctly in `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job` but when I run `Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.last` or `Delayed::Job.last` I don't see the job I just created.

Could this be a matter of my Rails environment being in development or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It looks like if I add a `.save` to the end of `self.class.new(car).delay(...).billing_failed_for_subscriptions` it will save a record in the database.

Comment: Perhaps you disabled delaying jobs globally for development purposes by `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false`? In that case the jobs are not saved but invoked right away.

Comment: This is what it was. It was set to false in development. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

- StripeMailer::billing_failed_for_subscriptions(car.owner.email).deliver

use

- StripeMailer::billing_failed_for_subscriptions(car.owner.email).deliver_later
  Then in the console you can check it as Delayed::Job.last

Comment: I'm getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'deliver_later'` error

Comment: Try using StripeMailer.billing_failed_for_subscription(car.owner.email).deliver_later
Also add this gem in your gemfile and install it https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
After installation run the migration and it will work fine.

Comment: @Fakhir_Shad it looks like this requires Rails 4.2 (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-42) and we're still in 4.0 for the moment. I have the delayed_job gem btw.